# Anyways to speed up mapdb?

Tags: java, database, hash, hashmap

I tested mapdb with integer keys and string values to insert 10,000,000 elements inside.  Here is what I see:

```
Processed 1.0E-5  percent of the data  / time so far = 0  seconds 
Processed 1.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 7  seconds 
Processed 2.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 14  seconds 
Processed 3.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 20  seconds 
Processed 4.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 26  seconds 
Processed 5.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 33  seconds 
Processed 6.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 39  seconds 
Processed 7.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 45  seconds 
Processed 8.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 53  seconds 
Processed 9.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 60  seconds 
Processed 10.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 66  seconds 
Processed 11.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 73  seconds 
Processed 12.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 80  seconds 
Processed 13.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 88  seconds 
Processed 14.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 96  seconds 
Processed 15.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 102  seconds 
Processed 16.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 110  seconds 
Processed 17.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 119  seconds 
Processed 18.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 127  seconds 
Processed 19.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 134  seconds 
Processed 20.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 141  seconds 
Processed 21.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 149  seconds 
Processed 22.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 157  seconds 
Processed 23.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 164  seconds 
Processed 24.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 171  seconds 
Processed 25.00001  percent of the data  / time so far = 178  seconds 
....
```

About 2.5 million instances are put in the map within 178 seconds. For 10 millions it is around 12 mins.

Then I switched into more complicated values and the speed highly dropped (It took 3-4 days to add the whole 10,000,000 instances into the map). Anyone has any suggestions to speed up  mapdb insertions? Any prior speed related experience/problem with MabDB?

There is also an evaluation here: http://kotek.net/blog/3G_map

Update: I used the common procedure for creating the map. Here is a pseudocode:

```
DB db = DBMaker.newFileDB()....; 
... map = db.getHashMap(...);
loop (...) {   
map.put(...);
} 
db.commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

MapDB author here.

For start use specialized serializers they are bit faster:

Map m = dbmaker.createHashMap("a").keySerializer(Serializer.LONG).valueSerializer(Serializer.LONG).makeOrGet()

Next for import I would recommend to use Data Pump with TreeMap. An example is here:
https://github.com/jankotek/MapDB/blob/master/src/test/java/examples/Huge_Insert.java

Comment: Thanks for the response. How is this "specialized serializer"  different from the standard one? (See my update above in the question, please)

Answer (score 0):

From official site of [mapdb](http://www.mapdb.org/) I see follow:

> Concurrent - MapDB has record level locking and state-of-art
>   concurrent engine. Its performance scales nearly linearly with number
>   of cores. Data can be written by multiple parallel threads.

I thought, that's it, and wrote simple test:

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentNavigableMap;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.mapdb.*;

public class Test {
  private static final int AMOUNT = 100000;

  private static final class MapAddingThread implements Runnable {
    private Integer fromElement;
    private Integer toElement;
    private Map<Integer, String> map;
    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

    public MapAddingThread(CountDownLatch countDownLatch, Map<Integer, String> map, Integer fromElement, Integer toElement) {
      this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
      this.map = map;
      this.fromElement = fromElement;
      this.toElement = toElement;
    }

    public void run() {
      for (Integer i = this.fromElement; i < this.toElement; i++) {
        map.put(i, i.toString());
      }
      this.countDownLatch.countDown();
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
   // int cores = 1;
    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(cores);
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);
    int part = AMOUNT / cores;
    long startTime = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("Starting test in " + cores + " threads");
    DB db = DBMaker.newFileDB(new File("testdb5")).cacheDisable().closeOnJvmShutdown().make();
    Map<Integer, String> map = db.getHashMap("collectionName5");
    for (Integer i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
      executorService.execute(new MapAddingThread(countDownLatch, map, i * part, (i + 1) * part));
    }
    countDownLatch.await();
    long endTime = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("Filling elements takes : " + (endTime - startTime));
    db.commit();
    System.out.println("Commit takes : " + (new Date().getTime() - endTime));
    db.close();

  }
}
```

And got results:

> Starting test in 4 threads
>
> Filling elements takes : 4424
>
> Commit takes : 901

Then I run the same in one thread:

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentNavigableMap;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.mapdb.*;

public class Test {
  private static final int AMOUNT = 100000;

  private static final class MapAddingThread implements Runnable {
    private Integer fromElement;
    private Integer toElement;
    private Map<Integer, String> map;
    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

    public MapAddingThread(CountDownLatch countDownLatch, Map<Integer, String> map, Integer fromElement, Integer toElement) {
      this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
      this.map = map;
      this.fromElement = fromElement;
      this.toElement = toElement;
    }

    public void run() {
      for (Integer i = this.fromElement; i < this.toElement; i++) {
        map.put(i, i.toString());
      }
      this.countDownLatch.countDown();
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    int cores = 1;
//    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(cores);
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);
    int part = AMOUNT / cores;
    long startTime = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("Starting test in " + cores + " threads");
    DB db = DBMaker.newFileDB(new File("testdb5")).cacheDisable().closeOnJvmShutdown().make();
    Map<Integer, String> map = db.getHashMap("collectionName5");
    for (Integer i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
      executorService.execute(new MapAddingThread(countDownLatch, map, i * part, (i + 1) * part));
    }
    countDownLatch.await();
    long endTime = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("Filling elements takes : " + (endTime - startTime));
    db.commit();
    System.out.println("Commit takes : " + (new Date().getTime() - endTime));
    db.close();

  }
}
```

And got results:

> Starting test in 1 threads
>
> Filling elements takes : 3639
>
> Commit takes : 924

So, if I am doing everything correctly , then it seems like mapdb **not scalable for number of cores**.

Only things that you can play with only:

- Api methods (e.g. encryption switching, caching, tree map/hash map usage)
- Trying to change capacity of the map via Reflection

Comment: Nice @Maksym! (1) So, your experiments shows that, unlike what mapdb people say, the speed does not scale with the number of threads. I suspect that it is due to low number of instances (perhaps if you increase the instances to 10,000,000 we will see some gain.)   (2) What is the role of the db.commit(); ? I mean, I noticed that even before running "commit()" mapdb starts to write on disk. I wonder why we do a commit before closing the database.